echarts - series colorStops produce incorrect coloring
Recently I have tried using echarts to create linechart but failed to achieve results based on colorStops.
In the example image below, you can see setup using colorStops, but the thing is, yellow color should be drawn up to value of 100, but it is not. Here we are using global: true property.
The problem seems to be that it is not only shifted by itself, but somehow painted in exponentially wrong way.

Have also tried without global:true:

The thing is we are also tried to use visualMap to do that, but we need apply gradient between colors, and it seems to not be supported there. Is that correct?
Any ideas?

Please don't use images for code; the echarts test editor has a "Share" button which creates a link that you can paste for us to test your code.

If you wanted yellow on top, you should have made the gradient y = 1, and y2 = 0; you seem to be confused by the fact that y and y2 in the gradient definition are increasing downwards (graphical space), while the data values ("real" space) are represented increasing upwards on the y axis. Thus, for your the relative case, the color is magenta from top (max-value = (1-0)*400 ---> gradient.y=0) to half height (y = (1-0.5) * 400 ---> gradient.y=0.5), from there to (y = (1-0.8)*400 ---> gradient.y=0.8) it's black and the remaining to bottom is yellow.

@kikon yeah sorry, should have posted code, my bad.
Here is the example using global -- https://shorturl.at/oDNWX
We want to use global to make use of chart height in pixels, because the problem is that if the data changes in series, colorStops change (because offsets are related to that). Lets say we want to have offsets fixed.

The problem with global is that you don't know the exact space occupied by the chart area - you may start with the height of the chart container, but from that you have to deduce top/bottom padding (if any) and the vertical space occupied by the x axis. In this codepen, based on your code (with some changes in data to put points at y=300 and y=120) you should have the color stops at 600 (the max I set), 300, and 120. But you can clearly see that this is far from exact.

You can make it exact, by using the precise value to pixel conversion that is only available after the chart has rendered. In this updated codepen I added some code at the end that uses the already rendered chart to set the correct values for gradient.y and gradient.y2 and then calls again myChart.setOption to update the chart.

@kikon thank you very much for your effort and explanations. Will try to play around these options and see where we get to!

Sure, I hope it helps. If you'll think later to rephrase the question in a some specific way as for instance to start from color stops in real space y values, or even as fractions of y axis values from min to max, maybe I could write up an answer with code that might be helpful to others too.
